# jquery change values of 2 input text field

Tags: jquery

I want to create 2 text fields which will change at same time

```
<input type="text" class="text1">
<input type="text" class="text2">
```

They are created dynamically, so my code is:

```
$("body").on("keyup", function() {
    $(".text2").val($('.text1').val());
});
```

It works only when changing text1.
How can I write my script so I could change text2 too?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like

```js
var $ins = $('.text1, .text2').keyup(function() {
  $ins.not(this).val(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="text1">
<input type="text" class="text2">
```

Here we change the value of input field other than the one in which the keyup is done to the updated value.

---

Using event delegation

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.text1, .text2', function() {
  $('.text1, .text2').not(this).val(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="text1">
<input type="text" class="text2">
```

Comment: +1 though I encourage to keep `.on` on the input since he use it in the OP.

Comment: how can i use it with .on?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$("body").on("keyup", function() {
    var val1=$('.text1').attr('value');
    $(".text2").attr('value',val1);
});
```